# Encriptar imagen a través de algoritmo AES en java

Tags: java, java-8, encriptación, criptografía

Buenas tardes !!

Estoy intentando cifrar una imagen y mostrar como quedaría dicha imagen cifrada.
Me gustaría que fuera a través de los algoritmos AES y subtipo CBC.

Por ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class AESCBC {

// Definición del tipo de algoritmo a utilizar (AES, DES, RSA)
private final static String alg = "AES";
// Definición del modo de cifrado a utilizar
private final static String cI = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

/**
 * Función de tipo String que recibe una llave (key), un vector de inicialización (iv)
 * y el texto que se desea cifrar
 * @param key la llave en tipo String a utilizar
 * @param iv el vector de inicialización a utilizar
 * @param cleartext el texto sin cifrar a encriptar
 * @return el texto cifrado en modo String
 * @throws Exception puede devolver excepciones de los siguientes tipos: NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException
 */
public static String encrypt(String key, String iv, String cleartext) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), alg);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes());
        return new String(encodeBase64(encrypted));
}

/**
 * Función de tipo String que recibe una llave (key), un vector de inicialización (iv)
 * y el texto que se desea descifrar
 * @param key la llave en tipo String a utilizar
 * @param iv el vector de inicialización a utilizar
 * @param encrypted el texto cifrado en modo String
 * @return el texto desencriptado en modo String
 * @throws Exception puede devolver excepciones de los siguientes tipos: NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException
 */
public static String decrypt(String key, String iv, String encrypted) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), alg);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        byte[] enc = decodeBase64(encrypted);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(enc);
        return new String(decrypted);
}

}
```

Y el test donde lo pruebo es:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     String key = "92AE31A79FEEB2A3"; //llave
     String iv = "0123456789ABCDEF"; // vector de inicialización
     String cleartext = "hola";
     System.out.println("Texto encriptado: "+AESCBC.encrypt(key, iv,cleartext));
     System.out.println("Texto desencriptado: "+AESCBC.decrypt(key, iv,AESCBC.encrypt(key, iv,cleartext)));
     }

     }
```

Esto me muestra la cadena "Hola" encriptada y desencriptada, pero yo querría probar a hacerlo con una imagen, es decir, que cogiese dicha imagen o el contenido de la imagen, es que no se que cogería y mostrase dicha imagen encriptada,

¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Aes es un algoritmo que usa cifrado de bloques. Y bloques idénticos obtienen cifrados idénticos. En este artículo te muestran por qué no sería bueno usarlo para cifrar imágenes: [https://blog.cloudflare.com/padding-oracles-and-the-decline-of-cbc-mode-ciphersuites/]

Answer (score 2):

Fijate, en primer lugar, que el cifrado en realidad trabaja sobre los bytes, no sobre la cadena de caracteres; es por ello que existe la línea

```
cleartext.getBytes()
```

para que del texto pase a un `byte[]` y

```
decodeBase64(encrypted)
```

Esto igual ya lo tenías visto, por si acaso no viene mal para alguien más que lea la respuesta.

Entonces tu problema es leer el fichero con la imagen en un array de bytes para cifrarlo (tomando la entrada a un `ByteArrayInputStream`)

El resultado *cifrado* es otro `byte[]` que puedes guardar en un fichero; en realidad el base-64 está ahí sólo para que un humano pueda revisarlo (su origen es adjuntar contenidos binarios en correos dentro del contenido de texto, sin ser adjuntos)

Ahora, si te he entendido bien ¿quieres ver la "imagen cifrada"? No, eso no es posible; al cifrar la imagen original pierdes cabeceras e información de control del formato y no podrás abrirla, lo que tienes al cifrar ya no es un MIME-Type de ningún formato de imagen conocido o existente.

Comment: La única forma de "ver la imagen cifrada" sería que sacase el bitmap, lo cifrase y luego crease una nueva imagen a partir de el nuevo bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sirva.

[Encriptador de texto imagenes y archivos binarios](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/Java/3715-Encriptador-de-texto-imagenes-y-archivos-binarios.html)

Comment: la idea en SO es colocar respuestas completas que ayuden a toda la comunidad, aunque tu enlace pudiera ser útil; ¿qué pasa si la página deja de estar disponible?, es mejor colocar el contenido relevante justo aquí para poder servir como fuente de consulta a los demás usuarios checa [answer]